# Optimization problem (rectangle inscribed below parabola) - possible textbook mistake

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have been working on a textbook's Optimization problem but the answer that I got does not match the textbook's answer. I would like to make sure I got it right (I can't find any mistakes on my solution), so I would like to ask for someone's help. I would appreciate that.

**The problem:**

> A rectangle is located below a parabola, which is given by $$y = 3x- \frac{x^2}{2}$$ in such a way that its two superior vertexes are placed on the parabola and its two inferior vertexes are located on the $x$ axis. The left, inferior vertex, is placed on the point $(c,0)$. That said:
>   a) Show that the area of the rectangle can be represented by the equation $$A(c) = c^3 -9c^2 + 18c$$
>   b) Find the rectangle's height and width given that is has maximum possible area.
>
> c) What is that area?

Instead of typing the whole solution I will post an image with it (sorry for that but latex-ing it would take a lot of time!). You will find my solution below.

[image]

If that's helpful, **the textbook's answer** for b) and c) are $3-\sqrt{3} \times 3$ and $9 + 9\sqrt{3}$ respectively.

Thank you.

Comment: $base=2\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a slight error when trying to find the base:

$$c = 3-\sqrt{3} \implies b = 2(3-c) = \color{blue}{2\left[3-\left(3-\sqrt{3}\right)\right]} = 2\sqrt{3}$$

You forgot the $3$ in $(\color{blue}{3}-c)$ and found $b = 2c$ instead.

**Addition**: From here, using $h = 3$ as you found, you get

$$A = bh \iff A = 3\left(2\sqrt{3}\right) = 6\sqrt{3}$$

Try plugging in $c = 3-\sqrt{3}$ in $f(c)$:

$$f\left(3-\sqrt{3}\right) = \left(3-\sqrt{3}\right)^3-9\left(3-\sqrt{3}\right)^2+18\left(3-\sqrt{3}\right) = 6\sqrt{3}$$

Through [confirmation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/csqdpe1jlk), you can see this point coincides with the local maximum.

Comment: thank you I've fixed that mistake. Now I have $2 \sqrt{3}$ as a base and $3$ as the rectangle's height, which gives me an area of $A = 6 \sqrt{3} \ m^2$. Am I good? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that’s the correct answer!

Comment: thank you and have a great day =)

Comment: Glad to have helped! :-) You may want to mark the answer as accepted if it has helped resolved the issue.